# (qt6 + postgre) Driver not loaded, как подключить драйвер (macos)

Tags: qt, postgresql

Не могу разобраться, как либо создать драйвер(как указано в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/sql-driver.html#qpsql), да для qt5.6, но для 6й я просто не нашел нужного раздела), либо указать путь до драйвера(он отображается как существующий).

Конекшусь(пытаюсь) к локальной postgresql, установленной из brew в дефолтный путь (/opt/homebrew/var/pos...@15/data), сам qt установлен в users/murzabaev/Qt/..

Вывод из консоли.

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
```

В pro файл указал путь до папки с драйверами(самого драйвера я там не нашел).
[image: pro file]

qt6.4
postgresql 15

Не совсем по теме:
Недавно стал макось юзером, проблему(не решил!) обошел тем, что за виртуалил убунту и поднял бд с qt там, но хотелось бы, понять как все таки запустить данное приложение в дефелтной ос.
Я нашел что-то [похожее](https://forum.qt.io/topic/127348/installing-qt-with-postgresql-drivers-macos-m1/4), но так и не смог разобраться, он каким то образом проваливается в Application/Postgres.app/ (у меня такого апп нет), да и тема так и осталось не завершенной.

Comment: сам драйвер у вас есть, а загрузиться не может потому что не находит либы самой postgres. они должны лежать вместе с программой, либо быть доступны через path

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev, спасибо за ответ, я нашел те библиотеки, не подскажете как их правильно в патч добавить
я написал дефолтное includepath +=/путь до папки с либами/, мб я что-то не так делаю